# Firebase (....ContinueWith(task => ...) in a For-Loop

Tags: firebase, for-loop, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

First, this is the code:

```
 for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++)
 {    
      db.Child("Some Child").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
      {
           Debug.Log("j: " + j); // Here the Debug will show me that j = count
           if (task.IsFaulted)
           {
               // ERROR HANDLER
           }
           else if (task.IsCompleted)
           {
               // Some Code Here
            }
        });
  }
```

Ok, so my problem is that after the "....ContinueWith(task => ..." ' j ' will become directly equal to the count variable. Why this happens and how to solve it? Or is there another method to do that?

Answer (score 1):

> Ok, so my problem is that after the "....ContinueWith(task => ..." ' j
>   ' will become directly equal to the count variable. Why this happens
>   and how to solve it?

That's because you used `<=` instead of `<`. With `<=`, `j` must be equals to `count` for the loop condition to be met and finish. If you want `j` to be less than `count` then use `count-1` or simply use `<`.

So, that should be

```
for (int j = 1; i <= count-1; j++)
```

Or

```
for (int j = 1; i < count; j++)
```

Note that array  starts from 0 not 1 so `int j = 1;` should be `int j = 0;` but I have a feeling that's what you wanted to do and you are starting the loop from `1` on purpose.

---

Finally, another problem is your variable being captured in a loop because you are using lambda in the `ContinueWith` function. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp) post for more information. To use the `j` variable inside the `ContinueWith` lambda function, make a copy of it then use that copy instead of the j variable.

```
db.Child("Some Child").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
{

    //MAKE A COPY OF IT
    int jCopy = j;
    Debug.Log("j: " + jCopy); // Here the Debug will show me that j = count 
}
```

Complete fixed code:

```
for (int j = 1; i < count; j++)
{
    db.Child("Some Child").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        //MAKE A COPY OF IT
        int jCopy = j;
        Debug.Log("j: " + jCopy);

        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            // ERROR HANDLER
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            // Some Code Here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Not that what I mean. What I mean is that the ' j ' variable directly jump to 'count' even if it is (j < count) or (j <= count), so it will not be ( j = count - 1) for example, only ( j = count).

Comment: I know what you mean. Read my answer again. Read it again. See the second part where I also mentioned about  "variable being captured" and making a copy of it to fix. Also, there was a typo in your question with `i` .  I have the-same typo since I copied it directly from your question but just change that `i` to `j`. It's just a typo.

Comment: Ok, I think I get your idea, but you need to put the "int jCopy = j;" before "db.child("some...", and then after it we add "j = jCopy;" , to get it works. This solves the problem, but do you know why this happens? And thank you.